# Google Places Nearby API Success 200, but returns "INVALID_REQUEST" in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, google-api, google-places-api

I'm trying to make an iterative crawler for the Google Places API. As anyone who has used their API knows, the response only contains 20 results per page and I'm attempting to get the full list of results so I've created an loop which will execute a function if the next_page_token field is present. The most peculiar thing happens because it successfully retrieves and echos the first 20 results but fails to perform the second search, but doesn't throw any errors in Laravel. The code for this looks as follows (this is in Laravel)

```
public function getAllPlaces(){
        if (Auth::user()->id != '5') {
            return redirect('/userlanding')->with('error', 'Denied access');
        } else {
            $client = new Client();

            $types = 'park';

            $radius = '50000';

            $location = [

                'latitude' => '36.187740',

                'longitude' => '-92.731422'

            ];

            $keyword = '';

            $requestQuery = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={$location['latitude']},{$location['longitude']}&radius={$radius}&type={$types}{$keyword}&key=MYSUPERSECRETKEY";

            $response = $client->request('GET', $requestQuery);
            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

            $body = json_decode($body);

            $numofrecordspresent = 0;

            $data = $body->results;

            $results = collect();
            foreach($data as $result) {
                 $results->push($result;      
                 $numofrecordspresent = $numofrecordspresent + 1;
                }
            }

            if(isset($body->next_page_token)) {
                $loopData = [

                    'nexttoken' => $body->next_page_token,

                    'locationData' => $location,

                    'numofrecordspresent' => $numofrecordspresent,

                    'radius' => $radius,

                    'types' => $types,

                    'keyword' => $keyword,

                    'client' => $client,

                ];

                $this->loopedPlaceSearch($loopData);
            } else {
                return view('apireturnpage')->with('numofrecordspresent', $numofrecordspresent);
            }
        }
    }

    public function loopedPlaceSearch($loopData) {
        $client = new Client();

        $location = $loopData['locationData'];
        $numofrecordspresent = $loopData['numofrecordspresent'];
        $pagetoken = $loopData['nexttoken'];
        $radius = $loopData['radius'];
        $types = $loopData['types'];
        $keyword = $loopData['keyword'];

        $requestQuery = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={$location['latitude']},{$location['longitude']}&radius={$radius}&type={$types}{$keyword}&pagetoken={$pagetoken}&key=MYSUPERSECRETKEY";

        $response = $client->request('GET', $requestQuery);
        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        $body = json_decode($body);

        $data = $body->results;

        $results = collect();
        foreach($data as $result) {
             $results->push($result;      
             $numofrecordspresent = $numofrecordspresent + 1;
            }
        }

        if (isset($body->next_page_token)) {
            $loopData = [

                'nexttoken' => $body->next_page_token,

                'locationData' => $location,

                'numofrecordspresent' => $numofrecordspresent,

            ];


            $this->loopedPlaceSearch($loopData);
        } else {
            return view('apireturnpage')->with('numofrecordspresent', $numofrecordspresent);
        }
    }
```

At the moment, to elaborate on what I said earlier, the first function which is the one called from web.php works just fine, pushing all 20 results onto the results collection, but when there is more results (i.e. the next_page_token is present), the second function gets called but returns "INVALID_REQUEST" in the body. This is extremely weird because taking the exact actual query string from the second function that gets used but fails and putting it into my URL bar returns the proper response, ruling out any typos in the API call.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, seems to be a bug and I can't figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Your browser might automatically apply URL encoding in places where it is necessary. When making requests from within code, that usually doesn’t happen. So the very first thing you should do, is apply proper URL encoding to the parameters you are inserting into the URL there (or use `http_build_query` to begin with), instead of just doing rather naive string concatenation with a “fingers crossed & hoping for the best” attitude.

Comment: I can add encoding, but as you see in the code the same calling process is made in both the initially called function and the second function which means if the first request succeeds there shouldn’t be any reason the second one shouldn’t? Correct me if I’m wrong, which I am often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I made this post, but for those just finding this now with the same issue, I figured I'd explain why this happened and how I fixed it. Turns out, without a delay in the script, the server attempts to make another request while the other response is still being returned, which causes the issue in question. This is fixed very simply by adding a sleep() or usleep() before making each request, in order to prevent multiple calls at the same time.

EDIT (5/10/20): This solution is still valid, but the reasoning is not the same as I explained. The real reason why using a usleep() or sleep() function fixes this issue is because Google implemented a bottleneck on their API endpoints to prevent misuse. It only allows one request per 1-3 seconds depending on the API and anymore will cause this error to occur. I only know this because I reached out to Google directly and that was the response I received from a technical support employee at Google.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a closing parenthesis on both of your result pushes:

```
$results->push($result;
```

I do not know if this will fix it, but it bothers me!

Comment: OP here- on old account that my phone is logged in as- the simple push was in replacement to a much longer operation that wasn’t the root of the issue. The actual code is correctly punctuated. Will fix once I get home.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the php sleep(timeInSecounds>=1) function before you call more times in the row the google places api.
2. And the other point is your recurcive call of loopedPlaceSearch() function. You put the response to an variable which scope is limited by the function him self. better you put your response to an classmember.